# CSS image not floating next to nav

Tags: css, image, wordpress, navigation

for some reason I can't get the images to float next to the nav box in wordpress. If you visit http://bit.ly/Tz6lMs your know what I mean. Any ideas?

Comment: and how do I do this? new to stackoverflow.

Comment: OKay I will do this now. Thanks for the advice

Comment: All sorted, I didn't realise I had to accept people who helped me, I was just clicking yes to if the post had helped me or not, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the fact that your Nav is 21.3% width and your content is 88% width...

you should have this instead of 88%

```
#primary {
    width: 78%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cant find the problem in your page, since it is full of different classes, but this is how it should be done.
Hope you find it usefull.

[Click](http://jsfiddle.net/2dhSd/)